# I need to position backgrounds for text in a certain way

Tags: html

So I have two problems with my code right now.

- One is the background for the top text left text box does not move with the text, instead the text overflows the background.
- My other problem is the padding on the text box on the bottom right.  I want to have the same functionality as between the middle picture and the top text box. When I try to put padding on the bottom right text box it just puts padding on the text and not the white background.

```css
body {
  background-image: url("wall.jpg");
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.right {
  float: right;
  right: 0px;
  width: 50%;
  height:340px;
}
.campaign{
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
.campaignblurb{
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:white; 
  text-align:left;
  vertical-align: middle; 
  padding:20px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 42px;
  line-height: normal;
  color: #000000;
}
.p2coop{
float:left;
width: 50%;
font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 36px;
line-height: normal;
color: #000000;
background-color:white;
 text-align:left;
 vertical-align: left; 
 opacity: 0.6;
 height: 340px;
}
.editorblurb{
 width: 50%;
 float:right;
 height: 350px;
 font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
 font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 35px;
    line-height: normal;
    color: #000000;
 right: 100px;
 background-color:white; 
 background-origin: padding-box;
  text-align:left;
  vertical-align: middle; 
  padding:20px;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
.editor{
  width: 50%;
  height:350px;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="p2coop">The game’s two-player cooperative mode features its own entirely
 separate campaign with a unique story, test chambers, and two new player characters ATLAS and P-body, 
 referred to as Blue and Orange by GLaDOS, a pair of bipedal Personality Construct
 based androids. This new mode forces players to reconsider everything they thought they knew about portals.
 Success will require them to not just act cooperatively, but to think cooperatively.</div>
 <img src="portal_atlas_pbody.jpg" class="right">
 <img src="portal2campaign.jpg" class="campaign">
 <div class="campaignblurb">The single-player portion of Portal 2 introduces a cast of dynamic 
 new characters, a host of fresh puzzle elements, and a much larger set of devious test chambers.
 Players will explore never-before-seen areas of the Aperture Science Labs and be reunited with GLaDOS,
 the occasionally murderous computer companion who guided them through the original game.</div>
 <div class="editorblurb">
The Puzzle Creator (also known as Puzzle Maker or Editor) is a part of the Perpetual Testing 
Initiative in Portal 2, allowing the creation of single-player
and Co-op test chambers within a simple in-game editor.
</div>
 <img src="leveleditor.jpg" class="editor">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the text is overflowing the background is because you are setting a height, but not defining overflow or anything.

One option you have is to set `overflow: scroll` on the divs so that the user can then scroll to read the content and that will not alter the layout.

Otherwise you can remove the set heights on the divs and allow the text to fill as much space as it needs.

To solve the problem you are having with spacing the bottom text div and the image, simply set `margin-bottom: Xpx` on the bottom div. This will add white space between it and an element below it, padding adds space to the inside of the element which causes the background to also move.

```css
body {
  background-image: url("wall.jpg");
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  right: 0px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 340px;
}

.campaign {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.campaignblurb {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 20px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 42px;
  line-height: normal;
  color: #000000;
}

.p2coop {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: normal;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: grey;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: left;
  opacity: 0.6;
  height: 340px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.editorblurb {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  /* height: 350px; */
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: normal;
  color: #000000;
  right: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
  background-origin: padding-box;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 20px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.editor {
  width: 50%;
  height: 350px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="p2coop">
  Scrolling example with set height <br /><br /> The game’s two-player cooperative mode features its own entirely separate campaign with a unique story, test chambers, and two new player characters ATLAS and P-body, referred to as Blue and Orange by GLaDOS,
  a pair of bipedal Personality Construct based androids. This new mode forces players to reconsider everything they thought they knew about portals. Success will require them to not just act cooperatively, but to think cooperatively.
</div>
<img src="portal_atlas_pbody.jpg" class="right" />
<img src="portal2campaign.jpg" class="campaign" />
<div class="campaignblurb">
  The single-player portion of Portal 2 introduces a cast of dynamic new characters, a host of fresh puzzle elements, and a much larger set of devious test chambers. Players will explore never-before-seen areas of the Aperture Science Labs and be reunited
  with GLaDOS, the occasionally murderous computer companion who guided them through the original game.
</div>
<div class="editorblurb">
  Removing the height example <br /><br /> The Puzzle Creator (also known as Puzzle Maker or Editor) is a part of the Perpetual Testing Initiative in Portal 2, allowing the creation of single-player and Co-op test chambers within a simple in-game editor.
</div>
<img src="leveleditor.jpg" class="editor" />
```

I wouldn't recommend going with this layout on mobile screens so it you are looking into making it suitable for different screen sizes then look into [Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp), [flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp), or [CSS grid](https://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_grid.asp). This would allow you to position images before text that is relevant to it, or vice versa.